# SEO: disallowing Google from indexing forms?

Tags: seo, robots.txt, web-crawlers, google-index, forms

**From a SEO point of view, would you exclude forms from being indexed/crawled by Google or not?**

I mean my forms hardly ever contains keyword/keyphrases.

So I'm wondering what's the point of letting Google index them?

Moreover I think these form-pages might reduce PR of all other pages in the site cause the other pages are linking to the form-pages.

If your answer is "yes I would exclude them form indexing" would you simply use robots.txt to exclude them?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you include the fact that you edited the question (in your question) to make the answers and comments below make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iFrames and frames in general are not search engine friendly and I would not expect them to be indexed. However, that doesn't mean they won't be indexed now or in the future. If your goal is to keep that content out of the search engines you should be explicitly blocking it with robots.txt or the x-robots.tag header.

FYI, blocking this is silly because:

1) Content has nothing to do with PR at all

2) If the form covers content related to the site you're removing keywords and content from your website that can help you rank better.

3) Frames are not very accessible so you're alienating some of your users.

**update**

My answer is still don't block them. You gain nothing and only potentially hurt yourself by blocking pages that have to them and from them. Internal linking is important and clearly being overlooked here.

But if you're going to block them using the x-robots-tag header is ideal as robots.txt is not always honored as you would expect with the search engines. Of course, using both is probably the safest bet.

Comment: About (1): PR it's not about content, but about linking yes. I suppose a iframe is like a link, therefore if I exclude it from indexing/crawling PR should not leak toward that iframe. About (3) I don't understand what you mean, well if they are not very acceszible then I would say is better to block them so user won't click on a SER that would bring him directly on the iframe contents instead of being brought to the page that containes the iframe.

Comment: A frame is not a link. It's a frame. Very big difference. Plus you don't leak any real PR and it certainly won't affect your rankings in a meaningful way. This is clearly over optimization.

Comment: An iframe is one more page url in my site. Then if such page get indexed I suppose it will steal some PR from other pages (as any regular page does in my site). Don't you agree on this? I think it subtracts PR from the page that contains the IFRAME tag. How couldn't Google consider it as a sort of link to the IFRAME page?!

Comment: Your understanding of PR is very inaccurate. PR cannot be stolen. PR only involves links as it is a numerical representation of link popularity. A link is a link. You can't just call a frame a link all of a sudden. It's a frame and only a frame. Frames, or pages, don't steal PR from other pages and since frames are not accessible and ignored by search engines they are essentially invisible anyway. But blocking forms via iframes is unnecessary and does not benefit you.

Comment: @John: I understood your point when you say iframes are not links, I disagree on this, but I don't want to get into this now. Anyway I'm not blocking forms via iframes, I place forms in iframes because it's easier to test/modify them. So I normally place forms in iframes and I'm not going to change this just for SEO. I was only wondering if unallowing crawlers to index the form pages (that are shown in iframes) by using robots.txt migh be of any benefit for SEO purpose. You say that `frames are not accessible and ignored by seacth engines`, where did you read this?

Comment: @Marco regarding frames/iframes, this concept of their search unfriendliness has been around for a very long time, there's many many online resources discussing the ins-and-out of search engines and frames. Try http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=34445

Comment: @Mike Hudson: I probably wrote down bad the question. Beside iframe/frames, is it worth to let Google index/crawl pages taht conatin only a form. I'm going to update the question.

Comment: @John Conde: sorry I made a mistake talking about frames/iframes in the question. I updated the question. I'm only interested about whether to index or not pages that contain only forms.

Comment: People sometimes seem to forget that the main purpose of allowing Google to index your site is to make it easier for people to find stuff. If someone searches Google for "yourcompanyname contact" would you not want them to land on your contact form?

Answer (score -1):

II have a youtube Iframe in my website, after a week or 2, that youtube iframe over pass and out rank my ranking on google search, I think iframe affect page ranking.